# Reactive extensions handle event once

Tags: c#-4.0, event-handling, system.reactive

If I need one handle some event I usually code like this:

```
            // part of browser

            UrlEventHandler docReadyDelegate = null;
            var documentReady = new UrlEventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                view.DocumentReady -= docReadyDelegate; // unsubscribe
                // some code here. Fired then browser's document is ready!
            });

            docReadyDelegate = documentReady;
            view.DocumentReady += docReadyDelegate; // subscribe

            view.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

But as I think its not optimally and not beautiful. I know it possible to use Reactive Extensions to handle event once. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<UrlEventHandler, UrlEventArgs>(
            h => view.DocumentReady += h, 
            h => view.DocumentReady -= h)
        .Take(1)
        .Subscribe(se =>
        {
            /* code run only once */
        });
```

It will fire only once because of the `.Take(1)` and it will deal nicely with all of the attaching and detaching of the event handler.